# javascript check whether a specific element (iframe) exist, if not, appendchild

Tags: javascript

i want to achieve some feature like this:

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
el.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
document.body.appendChild(el);
el.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.com');
```

and if  "ifrm" exists, jt won't create new iframe. if it doesn't exist, it will create that frame. i want to do this to avoid duplicate frame creation when user keeps click on the same button to generate frame.  is there a way to check whether a specific iframe exists? thanks

Comment: [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

Comment: a better solution would be to remove the button entirely, or unbind the click event from the button and disable it when you click on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with getElementById('ifrm') whether or not the frame with that id already exists. If not, create it. Like so:

```
if(!document.getElementById("ifrm")) 
   // Create the damn thing
```

If you wish to check if there is any iframe at all, you could use getElementsByTagName('iframe').

To make live a little easier, you can take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This is a Javascript library that helps you to create DOM objects and/or find them in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("ifrm"))
   //then it exists
else
   //it doesn't exist yet
```